# Unable to connect through virtual machine via Azure Bastion

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, bastion-host

I am facing some issue in connecting to Virtual Machine through Azure Bastion. I am getting the below error

> Bastion is in failed state. Please delete and recreate it.

Could you please let me know why I am getting the above error message and can anyone please suggest me a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could happen when the Azure Bastion does not make provision well or you are deleting the Bastion service(it takes a few minutes to delete the service).

After Bastion has been deployed to the virtual network, the screen changes to the connect page.

[image]

In this case, you could delete the failed Bastion service. I suggest re-creating an Azure Bastion Host with [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-create-host-powershell) or [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/create-host-cli) to avoid some portal issues.

For example

```
# create an AzureBastionSubnet in your Azure VNet.
az network vnet create -g $RgName -n $VNetName  --address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 --subnet-name AzureBastionSubnet  --subnet-prefix 10.0.0.0/24

# create a public IP address. The public IP address must be in the same region as the Bastion resource you are creating.
az network public-ip create -g $RgName -n $publicip --sku Standard

# create a bastion host in the same region as your VM
az network bastion create --name $name --public-ip-address $publicip --resource-group $RgName --vnet-name $VNetName --location $location
```

It takes about **5 minutes** for the Bastion resource to create and deploy. Please be patient.